# How can I set the length, when creating a BSTR (using _bstr_t wrapper) by a native string?

Tags: c++, string, com, bstr, null-terminated

When creating a [`BSTR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221069%28v=vs.85%29) (using [`_bstr_t`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) as wrapper class) I have to use some of the [constructors of `_bstr_t`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k3ebasf%28v=vs.80%29). Since a `BSTR` is a length prefixed string that may contains null-characters, there must be a possiblity to create such a string using a native string without relying on the null-termination of the given native string.

To give an example:

```
wchar_t* pwNativeString = L"abc\0def\0\0ghi\0\0\0"; // + automatic "\0"

// Now I want to create a BSTR using _bstr_t by this string.
_bstr_t spBSTR = _bstr_t(pwNativeString);
```

The problem is that the constructor relies on the null-termination of `pwNativeString`. So the resulting `BSTR` is just `"abc"` and nothing more. So my question is: *How to create a `BSTR` or `_bstr_t` and deliver a pointer to an array with a specific length?* In the following a pseudo-code example:

```
_bstr_t spBSTR = _bstr_t(pwNativeString, 15);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`SysAllocStringLen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f98bff39-bc5f-4a81-85d7-d5228e20fbc8%28VS.85%29) to allocate the `BSTR`, and then use the two-argument `_bstr_t` constructor to create a `_bstr_t` object from it. If you set the second parameter to `true`, then you'll need to call [`SysFreeString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f230ee3-5f6e-4cb9-a910-9c90b754dcd3%28VS.85%29) afterward. Otherwise, the `_bstr_t` object owns the string and will free it for you.

```
BSTR bstrIn = SysAllocStringLen(L"abc\0def\0\0ghi\0\0\0", 15);
_bstr_t spBSTR(bstrIn, false);
```

Comment: By the way - did you know where the length is stored? Is it part of the character array? Is it a structure or what is it?

Comment: By the way, for easily using this I will use this macro - if it helps someone: `#define _bstr_t_create(str, len) _bstr_t(SysAllocStringLen(str, len), false)`

Comment: The length is stored in an implementation-defined location determined by the OS. That's commonly in the four bytes immediately preceding the first character of the string, but rather than assume that, you can just call `SysStringLen`.